# Script > Search directory for multiple file names and then delete them

Tags: vb.net, windows, vb.net-2010

I need to write a script for deleting multiple files. I have been able to write one that searches a directory for one file name and then deletes it but I need the ability to specify more than one file name at a time and delete all of them if found. It should be noted that I am not trying to search for duplicate file names. Right now I have to edit the script each time I want to search for a file to delete it, I have to do this several times per day with a dozen or so files at a time.....the file names are never the same; once used they will never be used again.

Here is an example of what I'd like to achieve.

Search C:/junk/log/ for  "**ff12345a.txt**"  and "**hg76930b.dr1**"  and "**890379.rt**" then delete all.

For now I am attempting to do this through a bat file but eventually it would be cool to have a vb program that has a GUI allowing me to specify multiple files I want to search for rather than editing the script each time.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If possible, I'd like to start off with the bat script before I spend time creating a VB program with GUI.

Answer (score 1):

```
    ' make a reference to a directory
    Dim di As New IO.DirectoryInfo("c:\")
    Dim diar1 As IO.FileInfo() = di.GetFiles()
    Dim dra As IO.FileInfo

   'list the names of all files in the specified directory
    For Each dra In diar1
   'Do what you want with dra / Use your delete code here
        ListBox1.Items.Add(dra)
    Next
```

To filter search change di.GetFiles() to di.GetFiles(“.extionsion”)