# How to search and delete multiple text files from a directory using code

Tags: vb.net, text-files, vb.net-2010

I have a treeview control on my form and from this form, I save data to text files to a desktop directory in the format:

- Dan Michael.TXT
- Dan Michael.GAT
- Michael Torns.STD

I also have a button on the form which the user can click to delete any node, after that node has been selected.

In my treeview, there is a node whose text is “Michael”.

What I want to achieve is that after the user selects this node, and then clicks the delete button, the node is deleted, and all text files in the desktop directory that have “Michael” in their names are also deleted.

I am able to specify the sub-folder in which the text files are found but do not know how to proceed to achieve my goal so would appreciate some help, please.

I am using Visual Basic 2010 Express.

```
‘This is the sub-folder directory in which the text files are found
Dim GB = New DirectoryInfo(Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop), "Student Names\" & TextBox1.Text))

Dim FGY As TreeNode 
    FGY = TreeView1.SelectedNode

‘Need help here…
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Script > Search directory for multiple file names and then delete them](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27945582/script-search-directory-for-multiple-file-names-and-then-delete-them)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the .GetFiles to list all files with specific search pattern :

```
Dim pattern As string = "*" & FGY.Text & "*"
    For Each fi In GB.GetFiles(pattern)
            fi.Delete
Next
```